# Web Api, TokenEndPointPath returns Http resource was not found in production

Tags: asp.net-web-api, server, production

I have Web Api. It works good on my local computer but when I publish it on my server/hosting. Only Url to request OAuth Token returns "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request". All others controllers works fine.

Any ideas why it happens only in production?

My Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http;

using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Api.Startup))]

namespace Api
{
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        ConfigureOAuth(app);

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);

        app.UseWebApi(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }

    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/v1/oauth/token"), //TODO: FROM WEB CONFIG
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1), //TODO: FROM WEB CONFIG
            Provider = new AuthorizationProvider()
        };

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
    }
}
}
```

Best Regards

Comment: I Have the same problem